Power automate flow stale connection with copilot studio
Anytime I try to run my copilot, which accesses a power automate flow through an action, it prompts me to re-establish the connection. When I try to establish the connection, it loads and stays stale.
Where I try to re-establish the connectionoJP9fx2A.png)
flow in power automate
child flow in power automate
I already tried deleting and reinstalling the action. I also tried to remove and reinstall the Microsoft teams action used within the flow.

Turns out the "Post a message in a chat or channel action" was causing it to not connect. Once I removed that action and replaced it with the "Send an email" action it worked.
